# The default constructor of "Framework::Graphics::Material" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, struct, constructor

***Edited: added Shader class.***

I'm writing a DLL library but MS VS intellisense and compiler complaining about Mesh constructor. If i change Material attribute in Mesh constructor to Texture all OK. I tried to change struct to class, but it doesnt worked. Deleting FFB_FRAMEWORK_API marcro doesnt worked too.

DataStrictures.h

```
    struct Vertex {
        // position
        glm::vec3 Position;
        // normal
        glm::vec3 Normal;
        // texCoords
        glm::vec2 TexCoords;
        // tangent
        glm::vec3 Tangent;
        // bitangent
        glm::vec3 Bitangent;
    };
    struct Texture
    {
        unsigned int id;
        std::string type;
    };
```

main.h

```
#ifdef FFB_FRAMEWORK_EXPORTS
#define FFB_FRAMEWORK_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define FFB_FRAMEWORK_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

class FFB_FRAMEWORK_API Shader
        {
        public:
            unsigned int ID;
            // constructor generates the shader on the fly
            Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr);

            // activate the shader
            void use();

            // utility uniform functions
            void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const;

            void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const;

            void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const;

            void setVec2(const std::string &name, const glm::vec2 &value) const;

            void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y) const;

            void setVec3(const std::string &name, const glm::vec3 &value) const;

            void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z) const;

            void setVec4(const std::string &name, const glm::vec4 &value) const;

            void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w);

            void setMat2(const std::string &name, const glm::mat2 &mat) const;

            void setMat3(const std::string &name, const glm::mat3 &mat) const;

            void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const;

        private:
            // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
            void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type);
        };

struct FFB_FRAMEWORK_API Material
        {
            Shader shader;
            std::vector<Texture> textures;
        };
class FFB_FRAMEWORK_API Mesh
        {
        private:
            std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
            std::vector<unsigned int> m_indices;
            Material m_material;
            unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
            void SetupMesh();
        public:
            Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices, Material material);
            void Draw(Shader shader);
        };
```

Mesh.h

```
Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices, Material material)
{
    m_vertices = vertices; 
    m_indices = indices;
    m_material = material;
    // now that we have all the required data, set the vertex buffers and its attribute pointers.
    SetupMesh();
}
```

Compiler complaining right before m_verticies = vertices

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E1790   the default constructor of
>   "Framework::Graphics::Material" cannot be referenced -- it is a
>   deleted function  FFB_Framework   c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\FFB\FFB_Framework\Mesh.cpp  7

Edited.
If i changing constructor to

```
 Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices, Material material):m_vertices(vertices),m_indices(indices),m_material(material)
{SetupMesh();}
```

Compiler throw that errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __cdecl Framework::Graphics::Material::~Material(void)"
>   (__imp_??1Material@Graphics@Framework@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function
>   "public: __cdecl Framework::Graphics::Mesh::Mesh(class
>   std::vector >,class
>   std::vector >,struct
>   Framework::Graphics::Material)"
>   (??0Mesh@Graphics@Framework@@QEAA@V?$vector@UVertex@@V?$allocator@UVertex@@@std@@@std@@V?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@4@UMaterial@12@@Z) FFB_Framework   C:\Users\Anton\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2017\Projects\FFB\FFB_Framework\Mesh.obj   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __cdecl Framework::Graphics::Material::Material(struct
>   Framework::Graphics::Material const &)"
>   (__imp_??0Material@Graphics@Framework@@QEAA@AEBU012@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: __cdecl Framework::Graphics::Mesh::Mesh(class
>   std::vector >,class
>   std::vector >,struct
>   Framework::Graphics::Material)"
>   (??0Mesh@Graphics@Framework@@QEAA@V?$vector@UVertex@@V?$allocator@UVertex@@@std@@@std@@V?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@4@UMaterial@12@@Z) FFB_Framework   C:\Users\Anton\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2017\Projects\FFB\FFB_Framework\Mesh.obj   1

Does anyone know where error?

Comment: Guess - `Mesh::Mesh` takes `Material` by value (makes a copy) and `Shader shader;` (member of `Material`) is not copyable.  Whats the definition of `Shader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a assignment for the `m_material` variable. Before entering the body of the `Mesh` constructor the default constructor of m_material is called, which is deleted. You may reorganize the constructor like this and provide a matching constructor for Material

```
Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices, Material material) : m_vertices(vertices), m_indices(indices), m_material(material)
{
    // now that we have all the required data, set the vertex buffers and its attribute pointers.
    SetupMesh();
}
```